# Will PDF 2.0 compatible with PDF 1.x

Tags: pdf, standards

Will a valid PDF 1.x document be a valid PDF 2.0 document? Will PDF 1.x readers gracefully accept PDF 2.0 documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those who worked on PDF 2.0 in ISO made great effort to be as compatible with present-day implementations as possible and to break as little as we could possibly do. Some changes (like adding UTF-8 string object support) weren't possible in a means that is totally backward-compatible. Most changes, however, are clarifications to the standard and updates to better align the ISO standard to the behaviors of implementations. For example, the section on Tagged PDF was rewritten in a way that is much clearer and easier to understand, and includes a new tag set for PDF 2.0 that does not match the PDF 1.7 tag set. However, the PDF 2.0 tag set is not the default - the default remains the PDF 1.7 tag namespace - so that Tagged PDF files can be promoted to PDF 2.0 without the tags needing to be rewritten.

PDF 2.0 is an evolution of the PDF standard, not a drastic change to the specification. It does include some new capabilities - such as the ability to specify string objects in UTF-8 format - that PDF 1.7 viewers will not be able to handle correctly. However, most PDF 1.7 viewers should handle most PDF 2.0 files perfectly well. In this respect, your comparison to PDF 1.6 vs. PDF 1.7 is a fair comparison: viewers that don't know about PDF 2.0 revisions or features will either ignore these or not handle these correctly. However, I expect most PDF 2.0 files will be written in a way where they are compatible with present-day PDF 1.7 viewing implementations.

If you're interested in more information, Peter Wyatt's presentation at PDF Days Europe 2017 can be downloaded from https://www.pdfa.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/PDF20Keynote.pdf ; or you can watch it via https://youtu.be/AR4lGlDh9Ac.

Disclaimer: I am the chairman of the PDF Association

Answer (score 1):

No, a PDF 1.x document is not a valid PDF 2.0 document.

A PDF 1.x document could be a valid PDF 2.0 document if at the very least the only changed required was the version number in the PDF. There are a number of other changes required for PDF 2.0 though like appearances for annotations being defined in the PDF (in 1.x they were optional and viewers would generate them on the fly if not found or simply not display anything) and the deprecation of XFA.

Some PDF 1.x readers may accept PDF 2.0 documents. It will be up to the vendor though to determine what level of support they offer for PDF 2.0 .

Comment: So is PDF 2.0 a huge breaking change from 1.x or are the differences between PDF 1.7 and 2.0 similar to the differences between 1.6 and 1.7?

Comment: It is not a huge breaking change, there are a number of things that have been deprecated and should not be written into PDF 2.0 files and a number of issues in the specification addressed where the language was ambiguous and was interpreted differently by implementors. There are also new features, some of which are things that have been supported in PDF through extension levels defined on top of 1.7 by Adobe. For more specific information about these changes check out the PDF Association article : https://www.pdfa.org/what-will-pdf-2-0-bring/